# Drop columns based on threshold on string values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame as below

```
lst =[['', '2014', '2014', '2014', '2014', '2015', '2015', '2015', '2015', '2016', '2016', '2016','2016'],
      ['Stmnt of Oper:', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',''],
      ['Net sale', '', '$', '88,988', '', '', '$', '107,006', '', '', '$', '135,987', ''],
      ['Oper inc', '', '$', '178', '', '', '$', '2,233', '', '', '$', '4,186', ''],
      ['Net inc', '', '$', '(241', ')', '', '$', '596', '', '', '$', '2,371', ''],
      ['EPS', '', '$', '(0.52', ')', '', '$', '1.28', '', '', '$', '5.01', ''],
      ['', '2014', '2014', '2014', '2014', '2015', '2015', '2015', '2015', '2016', '2016', '2016','2016'],
      ['Bal Shts:', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',''],
      ['Tot asts', '', '$', '53,618', '', '', '$', '64,747', '', '', '$', '83,402', ''],
      ['Tot oblig', '', '$', '14,794', '', '', '$', '17,477', '', '', '$', '20,301', '']]

df=pd.DataFrame(lst)
```

[image: original df]

I want to select from the data frame only those columns which has numerical/ string values like columns `0`,`3`,`7` and `11`, so my output should look like below

[image: result df]

**Is there a simpler way to get this?**
what i tried is as below,

```
 df.replace(to_replace=['$', ')', ')%', '%'],value='',inplace=True)
 mask = df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts,normalize=True).loc[''] > 0.5
 df = df.loc[:,~mask]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you case , you can check `isin`

```
yourdf=df.loc[:,df.isin(['$', ')', ')%', '%','']).sum()/len(df)<=0.5]
```